# Родовое понятие и неполные предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Комментарий к фильму на сайте:

> *Хороший фильм!*

У фильма есть конкретное название (*Девчата*). Можно ли считать, что слово *фильм* здесь родовое понятие и само предложение схоже на неполное предложение *Хороший актер!* Или это предложение ближе к случаю *Великолепный вид!*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть фильм "Девчата", родовое понятие + название. Но всё это не имеет отношения к ситуации.

А ситуация такая: люди посмотрели конкретный фильм и оценивают его: **"ХорОший фильм!"**

Двусоставное предложение, ударение падает на сказуемое ***хороший***.

Сочетание *хороший фильм* может являться изолированным номинативом в таком предложении: Хороший фильм, как его создать?

Comment: Прилагательное стоит перед подлежащим-существительным. Почему сказуемое, а не определение?

Comment: Спасибо! Можно ли здесь допустить две трактовки: 1 - номинативное оценочное предложение (в частности, Бабайцева В.В. выделяет тип предложений Молодец!), 2 - двусоставное с инверсией (если интонационно выделено прилагательное)?